Hibernate ReturningWork - how do I print sql generated by ReturningWork?
How do I print the queries generated by Hibernate ReturningWork. As it uses jdbc connection the queries are not printed in the logger file after setting org.hibernate.SQL to INFO. May I know what property should I enable to print the queries generated by ReturningWork.
I am using Hibernate version - 5.3.36.Final
Spring Boot - 2.3.12.RELEASE
Thanks for your time to read the question. Any help appreciated!

ReturningWork is an interface which doesn't specify what and how could be done with the jdbc connection. Hibernate itself has only an abstract implementation of this interface. It is very likely that your implementations of this interface do not use hibernate to generate queries. If those implementations do not provide any logging options and you can't modify their code, you could try to configure logging on the jdbc side. Check How to enable logging for SQL statements when using JDBC
